# Problem with Euler's formula

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

My brother has came up with this equality:

$$
{e}^{i\pi} = -1 \quad\Rightarrow\quad {\left({e}^{i\pi}\right)}^{2} = 1 \quad\Rightarrow\quad \boxed{2\pi i = 0}
$$

But that result sounds impossible, so, where is the error?

Comment: In complex $e^x=e^y$ doesn't imply $x=y$.

Comment: It is **not true** that, for $z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$,
$$
e^{z_1}=e^{z_2}\implies z_1=z_2
$$

Comment: the exponential function is $2\pi i$-periodic, it means that $$e^x=e^{x+2\pi i},\quad\forall x\in\Bbb C$$